# Create Vue component documentation library for private use

Tags: nuxt.js, vuepress

I want to create a docs site for my Vue components, my question is: do I need to start a completely new project just for component documentation site or I can simply create a new branch in my exsiting project, for example, called "docs" branch then start my work there?
I am using Nuxt 3, and I am considering VuePress for creating the documentation site.

I've tried Vue-styleguidist but found it a bit cumbersome, so I start looking for a new solution, then end up considering with VuePress.

If I make you confuse at any point, please let me know.
Thank you!